# NextJS Route Same Page for Username?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, routes

I have one page is index.js. I want this page to come with both the home page and the username page. How can you do this?

localhost:3000 -> is home page
localhost:3000/username -> is user's page

in NextJS [username].js not working for me

Comment: What is the error that is popping up?

Comment: if i use [username].js duplicate codes for index.js, i don't want this way

Comment: Try index.js under [username] folder

Comment: Assuming you'd only have the `/pages/[username]` page, you can either setup a [`rewrites`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites) rule to map the `/` path to the username page, or use [Middleware](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware) to do the URL rewrite.